# Does DeleteAll in SQLite reset the AutoIncrement

Tags: sqlite-net

If I call the DeleteAll or DeleteAllAsync in SQLite will it reset the AutoIncrement property for a given table?

Comment: I think it is faster to test it and see the result than asking and waiting for answer.